# Kafka transactional producer — read_committed shows the records despite abort

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I wrote this simple program to test the new transactional producer in Kafka:

```
package test;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;


class kafkatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "hello-world-producer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);

        producer.initTransactions();
        producer.beginTransaction();

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("topic", "hello", "world"));  
        producer.flush();

        producer.abortTransaction();

        producer.close();
    }
}
```

but when I consume with `isolation.level=read_committed`, that very record shows up:

```
--- ~ » kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
        --topic topic \ 
        --from-beginning \ 
        --consumer-property isolation.level=read_committed

world
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use `read_committed` with the console consumer, you need to specify the `--isolation-level` option:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
--topic topic --from-beginning --isolation-level=read_committed
```

This option otherwise defaults to `read_uncommitted` and overrides the value you are passing via `--consumer-property`.

Comment: 2 hours lost in my life

Comment: exactly... lost more than 1 hr trying to debug.